# Entity Framework: dynamically change model based on plugins found with MEF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mef

I am working on an application, which will be extendable via plugins using MEF. The application is using Entity Framework. The context is created by factory method:

```
public class DataContextFactory
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public DataContextFactory([ImportMany] IEnumerable<IModelCreator> modelCreators, [Import(AllowDefault = true)]IDatabaseInitializer<DataContext> initializer)
    {
        ModelCreators = modelCreators;
        Initializer = initializer ?? new DefaultDataContextInitializer();
    }

    public DbContext Create()
    {
        return new DataContext(ModelCreators, Initializer);
    }
}


public interface IModelCreator
{
    void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(IEnumerable<IModelCreator> modelCreators, IDatabaseInitializer<DataContext> initializer)
    {
        ModelCreators = modelCreators;
        if (initializer != null)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(initializer);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<IModelCreator> ModelCreators { get; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        foreach (var creator in ModelCreators)
        {
            creator.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

where each plugin defines it's own `IModelCreator`.
Entities will be then accessed by `DbContext.Set().

The problem is that EF won't create additional tables, it will either drop the db or throw exception (depending on initializer used). When I turn on migrations, I am not able to generate migration, because there is no model in project, where the `DbContext` is.

Will each plugin have to supply SQL script to create it's tables or is there a way for EF to add tables at runtime for entities imported with plugin?

If I implement my own `IDatabaseInitializer` how can I tell it to create missing tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext, TMigrationsConfiguration> Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293(v=vs.113).aspx).

I have created `CompositeDataContextInitializer` and changed my `DataContextFactory` to pass it to my `DataContext` as argument.

```
public class CompositedDataContextInitializer : MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, Migrations.MigrationConfiguration>
{
    protected virtual void Seed(DataContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        foreach (var seeder in ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<IDataSeeder>())
        {
            seeder.Seed(context);
        }
    }
}


[Export(typeof(IDbContextFactory<DbContext>))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class ContextFromCompositionFactory : IDbContextFactory<DbContext>, IDbContextFactory<DataContext>
{
    public DbContext Create() => new DataContext(ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<IModelCreator>(), new CompositedDataContextInitializer());

    DataContext IDbContextFactory<DataContext>.Create() => (DataContext)Create();
}


public interface IModelCreator
{
    void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(IEnumerable<IModelCreator> modelCreators, IDatabaseInitializer<DataContext> initializer)
    {
        ModelCreators = modelCreators;
        if (initializer != null)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(initializer);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<IModelCreator> ModelCreators { get; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        foreach (var creator in ModelCreators)
        {
            creator.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

There are still some problems with [TPT Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618293.aspx); if you want to store new classes which inherit from classes already in system, use [TPH Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292.aspx).